# Android isInterrupted() returns false after interrupting Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, interrupt

I have a thread waiting to be notified or to time out

```
  while (!isInterrupted()) {
   try {
    if (!semaphore.tryAcquire(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
      Context context = getContext();
      // this is where i do my stuff
      semaphore.aquire();
    }
  } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
     ignored.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Before i quit my app i call `Thread#interrupt()` on this thread. Now i debugged the interrupt seemed to be executed fine since the `InterruptedException` was thrown and the waiting has been canceled.
But for some reason `isInterrupted()` still returns true after this and the while loop keeps on running.

**Why is that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a boolean in your while loop condition term because when you send the interrupt command, it won't stop the thread and the thread itself decide when to stop itself

Comment: I know how to solve the problem. There are many ways you can do it. I could also just break the while if the interrupted exception is thrown. But my question was not how to fix it. My question was why this occurs in android?

Comment: Wow i can't believe i overlooked that detail. Threads interrupted status gets cleared if and only if the thread was waiting/sleeping. In all other cases it would behave as expected. I wonder whats the reasoning for that design choice. Oh well, thanks :)